# how do I use mysql real escape string?

Tags: php, mysql

The code here is still incomplete because I'm still going to ask you guys on what the proper format/syntax of using mysql escape string. Im still a beginner in php and I want to learn how to avoid sql injections. Is the code below correct?

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","mypwd");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con);




      $sqlque="INSERT INTO t2 (HOSPNUM, ROOMNUM, ADATE, ADTIME, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDNAME, CSTAT, AGE, BDAY, ADDRESS, TELNUM, SEX, STAT, STAT2, STAT3, STAT4, STAT5, STAT6, STAT7, STAT8, NURSE)
      VALUES ('$_POST[hnum]', '$_POST[rnum]', '$_POST[adate]', '$_POST[adtime]', '$_POST[lname]',  '$_POST[fname]', '$_POST[mname]', '$_POST[cs]', '$_POST[age]', '$_POST[bday]', '$_POST[ad]', '$_POST[telnum]', '$_POST[sex]', '$_POST[stats1]', '$_POST[stats2]', '$_POST[stats3]', '$_POST[stats4]', '$_POST[stats5]', '$_POST[stats6]', '$_POST[stats7]', '$_POST[stats8]', '$_POST[nurse]')"; 

         mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[hnum]),
            mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[rnum]);
  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[adate]);
```

Comment: it is recommended to not insert your real password in the question

Comment: good... a little bit of research wouldn't be a trhouble, this is super-basic stuff you can search it directly on php.net, dont overflow with weekly recurrent problems i believe this is not the stackoverlow stands for ....

Comment: @useless Admittedly it's not one of the most exiting questions, but it is valid and reasonably well asked. Nobody said questions have to be hard to deserve to be asked here. Don't diss the noobs, you were one once as well. :)

Comment: But hopefully we will reach a state (anytime soon) where all those mysql\_real\_escape\_string related questions that are just different enough to not _immediately_ qualify as exact duplicate have been asked =]

Comment: @useless sometimes I've seen SO questions that I honestly thought were stupid receive thorough, well written, informative answers from which I learned a bit, which made me appreciate that someone was asking them. The great thing here isn't really the quality of the questions as much as the quality of the people answering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to escape the values *before* you put them into the query:

```
$hnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['hnum']);
$query = "INSERT ... VALUES('$hnum')";
```

If you have a lot of values, you can loop over them:

```
$values = $_POST;

foreach ($values as &$value) {
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
}

$query = "INSERT ... VALUES('$values[hnum]')";
```

Comment: would this stop sql injection?, is this true for all data types?

Comment: Yes, that's what `mysql_real_escape_string` is supposed to do, and it seems to work well enough. :)

Comment: With PHP 5.5, the extension mysql is depreciated and you should use mysqli instead.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

You're running mysql_real_escape_string on the variables AFTER inserting them into the string!

You'd want to do

```
   $hnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[hnum]),
   $rnum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[rnum]);
   $adate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[adate]);
   $sqlque="INSERT INTO t2 (HOSPNUM, ROOMNUM, ADATE, ADTIME, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, MIDNAME, CSTAT, AGE, BDAY, ADDRESS, TELNUM, SEX, STAT, STAT2, STAT3, STAT4, STAT5, STAT6, STAT7, STAT8, NURSE)
  VALUES ($hnum,$rnum,$adate', //etc.
```

Even better, don't create SQL queries out of string substitution at all. I suggest using PDO and prepared statements/parameterized queries. A prepared statement takes care of escaping the input for you. [Here's a good link](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/php-pdo.html) with a rundown of how to use PDO instead of the mysql_* commands.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this function like  this

```
....VALUES (".mysql_real_escape_string('$_POST[hnum]').",...
```